# Is it possible to read multiple files with a single filehandle in Perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have a few log files like these:

- /var/log/pureftpd.log
- /var/log/pureftpd.log-20100328
- /var/log/pureftpd.log-20100322

Is it possible to load all of them into a single filehandle or will I need to load each of them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pipes to virtually concat these files to a single one.

Comment: Thanks, that was the keyword I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

One ugly hack would be this:

```
local @ARGV = qw(
    /var/log/pureftpd.log 
    /var/log/pureftpd.log-20100328 
    /var/log/pureftpd.log-20100322
);

while(<>) {
    # do something with $_;
}
```

Comment: Use the special `ARGV` filehandle to implicitly open on each file in @ARGV.

Comment: This is what I do. I wouldn't call it "ugly", but it's not beautiful either.

Comment: Well, the reason it's "ugly" is because it's fragile: any other part of your code (or someone else's) can break this code by munging `@ARGV`. For for a quick one-off script, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not terribly hard to do the same thing with a different filehandle for each file:

```
foreach my $file ( @ARGV )
    {
    open my($fh), '<', $file or do { warn '...'; next };
    while( <$fh> )
         {
         ...
         }
    }
```